# VS2015 IISExpress extremely slow

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am having a problem where the built in IISExpress webserver for VS2015 is extremely slow.  To give you an idea of speed in the Contoso MVC5 demo web app it takes over a mnute to load the empty student screen.

In my actual project I have had out of memory errors a few times when dealing with large data sets even though my system has around 10gb free at the time.

I have 16gb ram and a decent i5 so I am not sure why it is going so slow.  When I query the database with SQL management studio it is fast.

It's far too slow to use right now so what can I do to speed this up?

Comment: Did you ever fine out what was the problem? I seem to be hitting a similar issue since reinstalling my laptop.

Comment: Yes I did but I cant remember what it was, I upgraded to 2017 now.  It was an obscure setting somewhere that fixed it